# How to obtain values from a date column at particular time instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `df` as follows:

```
  Date                values
20190101000000  1384.4801224435887
20190101000001  1384.5053056232982
20190101000002  1384.5304889818935
20190101000003  1384.5556725193492
20190101000004  1384.5808562356392
20190101000005  1384.606040130739
20190101000006  1384.631224204622
20190101000007  1384.6564084572635
20190101000008  1384.6815928886372
20190101000009  1384.7067774987179
20190101000010  1384.7319622874802
20190101000011  1384.757147254898
20190101000012  1384.7823324009464
20190101000013  1384.8075177255998
20190101000014  1384.8327032288325
20190101000015  1384.8578889106184
20190101000016  1384.8830747709321
20190101000017  1384.9082608097488
20190101000018  1384.9334470270423
20190101000019  1384.958633422787
20190101000020  1384.9838199969574
20190101000021  1385.0090067495285
20190101000022  1385.034193680474
20190101000023  1385.0593807897685
20190101000024  1385.0845680773864
20190101000025  1385.1097555433028
20190101000026  1385.134943187491
20190101000027  1385.160131009926
20190101000028  1385.1853190105826
20190101000029  1385.2105071894343
20190101000030  1385.2356955464566
```

where the `Date` column is of the format `%Y%m%d%H%M%S`. I take start date and end date as the user inputs and split it in a frequency of 1 second.

Now, I would like to take a second value of frequency from the user and obtain the value from the `values` column at that instant.

**Example:**

If the second resolution is 10secs, then the output must be as follows:

```
start              end                 value
20190101000000  20190101000010  1384.7319622874802
20190101000011  20190101000020  1384.9838199969574
20190101000021  20190101000030  1385.2356955464566
```

from the above `df`, we can see that if the resolution is 10sec, then the value at every 10th second must be obtained.

If the second resolution is 15mins, then the output must be as follows:

```
 start                 end             values
20190101000000  20190101001500  1407.2142300429964
20190101001501  20190101003000  1416.6996533329484
20190101003001  20190101004500  1424.2467631293005
```

How can this be done?

**My code till now:**

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

START_DATE = str(input('Enter start date in %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S format: '))
END_DATE = str(input('Enter end date in %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S format: '))
RESOLUTION = 'S'

dates = pd.date_range(START_DATE, END_DATE, freq = RESOLUTION)
dates = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(dates).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'), columns = ['Date'])
```

Comment: start column is different for `10s` and `15min`, for seconds is added 1 second, for minutes not. What is reason?

Comment: Hey @jezrael, thanks for pointing it out. It was my mistake. I corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare values of datetimes converted to underline format with modulo by timedelta, then crete new column by [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) and [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), last remove first row with `iloc`:

```
res = '10s'
m = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).to_numpy().astype(np.int64) % pd.Timedelta(res).value == 0

df = df[m].rename(columns={'Date':'end'})
df.insert(0, 'start', df['end'].shift())
df = df.iloc[1:]
print (df)
             start             end              values
10  20190101000000  20190101000010  1384.7319622874802
20  20190101000010  20190101000020  1384.9838199969574
30  20190101000020  20190101000030  1385.2356955464566
```

Last for add 1 second use:

```
df.loc[df.index[1:], 'start'] = (pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df.index[1:], 'start']) +
                                    pd.Timedelta('1s')).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
print (df)
             start             end              values
10  20190101000000  20190101000010  1384.7319622874802
20  20190101000011  20190101000020  1384.9838199969574
30  20190101000021  20190101000030  1385.2356955464566
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change data type of dates ==>
            import pandas as pd
            start_date = pd.to_datetime(START_DATE)
            end_date = pd.to_datetime(END_DATE)
            Resolution = start_date.minute